# SignalR losing connection expectedly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

I'm working on a Blazor application that using SignalR to trigger updates to the client.

However, we're seeing the client's **connection to the SignalR hub unexpectedly close on occasion**, and we're not sure why. It doesn't seem to caused by bad data in the messages, nor does it seem to be an issue with time outs.

This is the first application we're using SignalR in, so we would greatly apricate any suggestions about what might be causing these disconnections.

Comment: I suggest you to add more logs for troubleshooting, by the way, you might add reconnect mechanism within your client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0